# ora-00942 i created a connection with sys as user. but any of the tables created by me when used give this error

Tags: ora-00942

DECLARE 
REG_NO VARCHAR2(20) := & REG_NO;
p_d VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN

select d.PROVISIONAL_DIGNOSIS into p_d from Patient_Diagnosis d  where d.Registration_No = REG_NO;

insert into D_DETAIL( reg_no, p_d) values  ( reg_no , p_d );

END;

Answer (score 1):

Have you validate that your tables have been created correctly with the other user schema? Try with a connection of this one. You can use this queries in order to validate your tables existing in the schema:

```
 select * from user_objects where object_type = 'TABLE';

 select TABLE_NAME from ALL_ALL_TABLES;
```